# Render json to Grails domain list object

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

If there is one record in request.json the below code works

```
class BookController {
   def save = {
      def book = new Book(JSON.parse(yourJson))
      book.save(flush:true)
   }
}
```

But how to get bookList if there is multiple records in my request.JSON like:

```
[{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "MYNAME",
    "description": "test",
    "category": 1,
    "venue": null,
    "status": "Published",
    "deleted": false,
    "pricingPolicy": null
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "YZ",
    "description": "test6",
    "category": 2,
    "venue": null,
    "status": "Unpublished",
    "deleted": false,
    "pricingPolicy": null
}, {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "YZ",
    "description": "test6",
    "category": 1,
    "venue": null,
    "status": "Published",
    "deleted": false,
    "pricingPolicy": null
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request.JSON.each{ new Book( it ).save() }
```

should do